# doxygen ignore part of variable definition

Tags: doxygen

I would like to ask if you know a way how to make Doxygen ignore some keywords in code.
I use C in automation project (created in B+R Automation Studio) so there are Local and Global variables definitions.

Example:

**_Local** int variable1

**_Global** int variable2

This causes problems to Doxygen generated documentation.

What I need is to ignore bold  part of variable definition but I only found a way how to ignore bigger part of code (unfortunately syntax have to stay exactly as in example).

Thank you for your advice and/or answers.
Cheers,

Pavel

Comment: What type of problems do you have ?

Comment: When I generated doxy document from my code (see above) I had a problem that doxygen took more rows as single name for variable. I want to overcome this possibility by disabling _Local _Global for doxygen - it is not that important.

Comment: So in the output the variable name is to large to fit in the box. Which output format are we talking about? Please make a small example / picture so I can have a look, maybe there is a setting.

Comment: Output is HTML. But I am out of office right now - I will send screens later.

Comment: Ok, so I found the problem. I am going to look as stupid as possible, but I forgot to put ";" after one row.
Doxygen then wrote two variables on one row - not problem with _local / _global.
Thank you for your help - I will definitely use that ignore function in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The possibilities doxygen has for this are:

- create an `INPUT_FILTER` filtering away the unwanted parts
- have a look at the preprocessing possibilities and define all names
- define all the names in an include file and include this file conditionally and run with preprocessing

For all possibilities see the documentation in the configuration file section

Comment: Thank you for direction! I will try to get into it and will report back.

Comment: Beforehand also answer the comment I placed with the question (What type of problems do you have ?)